# What is the difference between $\dfrac{1}{3^{-2}}$ and $3^{-2}$

Tags: exponentiation

Stupid question but how in the world does 1/3^-2 not be the same thing as 3^-2?
 The first answer I got is 9, the second one I got is 0.111... Isn't the negative power just 1/3/3? What difference does it make when I do 1/1/3/3?

Comment: What do you even mean by 1/3/3 and 1/1/3/3?

Comment: To be clear, do you want to compare $$\frac1{3^{-2}} \quad\text{and}\quad 3^{-2}$$ or do you mean $$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-2} \quad\text{and}\quad 3^{-2}$$

Comment: $a \neq \frac{1}{a}$ unless $a$ is $\pm 1$

Comment: First, by "$1/3^{-2}$" do you mean $1/(3^{-2})$ or $(1/3)^{-2}$.  What you wrote **should** be interpreted as the first, but I have known it to be written when the second was intended.  Assuming you really mean $1/(3^{-2})$  then $3^{-2}= \frac{1}{9}$ so $1/(3^{-2})= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{9}}= 9$.

Comment: 1/3^-2. The 3 is to the power of -2. No parentheses involved. Also how do you do the power sub character?

Comment: Oh yes i do mean 1/(3^-2)

Answer (score 2):

Brackets are your friend. Without brackets it is difficult to determine the meaning of the symbols. You have
$$(1/3)^{(-2)} = (3^{-1})^{(-2)} = 3^{(-1)(-2)} = 3^2 = 9$$ 
whereas
$$3^{(-2)} = 3^{(2)(-1)}= (3^2)^{(-1)} = 9^{-1}.$$
But this demonstration is pointless unless you are clear on the meaning of the symbols $a^{-1}$ and $a^b$. This may be a topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by a fraction is the same as multiplying by its inverse.

\begin{equation}
3^{-2}=\frac{1}{3^2}=\frac19\approx 0.111111111\\ \\
\frac{1}{3^{-2}}
=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{3^2}}
=1\times\frac{3^2}{1}=3^2=9
\end{equation}